Help understanding baby Rudin's statement in 8.13
In baby rudin 8.13, the Fourier series is given in the way as (78). What I don't understand is why the expressions in (78) are equal? How can we use the periodicity and change of variable (maybe needed) to proof it?
page 188
page 189

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Just do $s=x-t$. Then $dt=-ds$ and your integral becomes
$$
-\frac 1{2\pi}\int\limits_{x+\pi}^{x-\pi}f(x-s)D_N(s)\,ds=\frac 1{2\pi}\int\limits_{x-\pi}^{x+\pi}f(x-s)D_N(s)\,ds.
$$
Next, you use $2\pi$-periodicity to conclude that the above integral, taken over an interval of length $2\pi$, is the same as the integral over the fundamental interval $[-\pi,\pi]$.
